# NHibernate with Autofac within ASP.NET (MVC): ITransaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, transactions, autofac

What is the best approach to managing NHibernate transaction using Autofac within web application?

My approach to session is

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
       .ContainerScoped();
```

For `ITransaction`, I have [found an example](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/trunk/src/Example/Remember.Persistence.NHibernate) on Google Code, but it relies on `HttpContext.Current.Error` when deciding whether to rollback.

Is there a better solution? And what scope NHibernate transaction **should** have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this a while ago:

http://groups.google.com/group/autofac/browse_thread/thread/f10badba5fe0d546/e64f2e757df94e61?lnk=gst&q=transaction#e64f2e757df94e61

Modified, so that the interceptor has logging capability and [Transaction] attribute can also be used on a class.

```
[global::System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TransactionAttribute : Attribute
{
}


public class ServicesInterceptor : Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor
{
    private readonly ISession db;
    private ITransaction transaction = null;

    public ServicesInterceptor(ISession db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(string.Format("{0}.{1}", invocation.Method.DeclaringType.FullName, invocation.Method.Name));

        bool isTransactional = IsTransactional(invocation.Method);
        bool iAmTheFirst = false;

        if (transaction == null && isTransactional)
        {
            transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
            iAmTheFirst = true;
        }

        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();

            if (iAmTheFirst)
            {
                iAmTheFirst = false;

                transaction.Commit();
                transaction = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (iAmTheFirst)
            {
                iAmTheFirst = false;

                transaction.Rollback();
                db.Clear();
                transaction = null;
            }

            log.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private bool IsTransactional(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        var atrClass = mi.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        foreach (var a in atrClass)
            if (a is TransactionAttribute)
                return true;

        var atrMethod = mi.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        foreach (var a in atrMethod)
            if (a is TransactionAttribute)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the solution. However, another question is to what methods should I apply [Transaction]? According to this http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alert?name=DoNotUseImplicitTransactions it seems I should always have a transaction if I have a session, however this solution requires me to manually add [Transaction] everywhere the session is used.

Comment: Check the modified version. You'll probably know how to modify it from there.

You can also skip the [Transaction] attribute altogether and always start the transaction. It's your choice. I needed the attribute, because sometimes I needed to do 2 things in different transactions.

I did it like this:
//No transaction attribute
public virtual void CallThis()
{
    Trans1(); //commits
    Trans2(); //commits
}

[Transaction]
public virtual void Trans1() { }

[Transaction]
public virtual void Trans2() { }

Comment: Could you explain the use case for two transactions? This is important since if I may also encounter a similar use case, I will look at the problem differently.

Comment: When a user tries to login with a certificate I have to do some selects and some updates in the database (that is the first transaction). 

If for some reason the user can't login (blocked account, error in network, whetever...) I have to do a rollback of everything I have done and update (in new transaction) a "Failed login count" up by one (and after it reaches 5 the account is blocked).

Comment: I think I understand the context now. I can start and commit a transaction automatically, but a good solution needs to allow manual rollbacks and manual restarts. I'll think about that a bit more, but right now I accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nitpick. its just a simple throw and not throw ex;

Answer (score 4):

When I use autofac I use the same container scoped method but instead of passing the same session to my Repository/DAO objects I pass an UnitOfWork that is container scoped. The Unit of work has this in the constructor.

```
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private ITransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
        _transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
    }
```

And the dispose is:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transaction != null &&
                            !_transaction.WasCommitted &&
                            !_transaction.WasRolledBack)
                _transaction.Commit();
            _transaction = null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Rollback();
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I am (ab)using the deterministic disposal stuff in autofac in order to manage this, and well I sort of like it.

The other thing is that I am basically only targeting an ASPNet environment and made a conscious decision that a transaction is tied to a web request. So a transaction per web request pattern.

Because of that I can do this error handling code in an IHttpModule:

```
    void context_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _containerProvider.RequestContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>().Rollback();
    }
```

I haven't taken a look at NHibernate.Burrow too closely but I'm sure there is something there that does most of this.

Comment: Your idea is very similar to what Autofac did, and I like it a lot. Unfortunately, I can not accept two answers, so I'll choose the one that was first (also dmonlord has much less reputation).

Answer (score -1):

I usually manage the transaction myself..

```
public ActionResult Edit(Question q){
try {
 using (var t = repo.BeginTransaction()){
  repo.Save(q);
  t.Commit();
  return View();
 }
 catch (Exception e){
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: It's the simplest solution, but it is a bit tedious and adds indent to the whole method.

Comment: sure, 2 lines and one indent, but some day you realize that you have to do two transactions in the same request or something like that..